# How to generate the dropdown menu when the button is clicked?

Tags: bokeh

My dropdown should list files in a directory whose contents change frequently. I have tried:

```py
menu = [(fname, fname) for fname in os.listdir(path)]
dropdown = Dropdown(label='files', menu=menu)

def on_click_handler():
    logger.info('dropdown on click')
    dropdown.menu = [(fname, fname) for fname in os.listdir(path)]
```

But when I click the dropdown button even the log statement is not created.

Comment: It is not clear what are you trying to do? Re-generate a `Dropdown` when you click on the same `Dropdown` ?

Comment: the dropdown displays file names in a directory. It should be up to date with the contents of the directory. I was thinking about regenerating the `menu` each time the dropdown is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Both examples are for Bokeh v1.1.0

When using Python callback in Bokeh server app:

app.py (run from command line `bokeh serve --show app.py`)

```
from bokeh.models import Dropdown
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc

files1 = ['file1', 'file2']
files2 = ['file3', 'file4']
dropdown = Dropdown(label = 'files', menu = [(fname, fname) for fname in files1])

def on_click_handler():
    dropdown.menu = [(fname, fname) for fname in files2]

dropdown.on_click(on_click_handler)
curdoc().add_root(dropdown)
```

When using JS callback in stand-alone Bokeh app:

app.py (run from command line `python app.py`)

```
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, ColumnDataSource, Select, Column, Dropdown
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc, show

files1 = ['file1', 'file2']
files2 = ['file3', 'file4']
menu1 = [(fname, fname) for fname in files1]
menu2 = [(fname, fname) for fname in files2]
dropdown = Dropdown(label = 'files', menu = menu1)

on_click_handler = CustomJS(args = {'dropdown' : dropdown, 'menu2': menu2}, code = ''' dropdown.menu = menu2;  ''')
dropdown.js_on_change('value', on_click_handler)
show(dropdown)
```

Comment: the server app example is exactly what I wrote and it doesn't work. Have you tried it? (Bokeh server version 1.0.3 (running on Tornado 5.1.1))

Comment: is there also an event for when the dropdown button is clicked? the `on_click` event is only triggered when menu items are clicked.

Comment: Not that I know.